# Possibility to fill in form OR upload file in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, file-upload

I am currently trying to make a platform for Formula One statistics. Which of course should be able to add circuits (my first form). And I let Django make the form so that works, but I would like the option to fill in manually or upload a file so he will parse the code.

Here is my form:

```
class CircuitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Circuit
        exclude = []
```

Here is the page that is displayed:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Welcome in the uploads</h1>
    <h2>You can add a single circuit here</h2>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            {{ form }}
        </table>
        <br><br>
        <h3>Or you can upload a file for bulk-uploading:</h3>
        <input type="file" name="circuitsFile" value="Upload a file">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

When you press the submit button, it doesn't do anything since the other fields need to be filled in first

If anyone knows the solution, I'd like to hear it :)

Comment: I think some fields from `Circuit` are required, you can override the fields in `CircuitForm` setting them not required, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: Yeah that might be a solution but I am more looking for the option to submit the values from the field or parse the file if there was one given by the user.